# What is the best way to loop over a list of URIs in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a music player in Android. To create a Song object, I have to repeatedly query various pieces of data using different URIs from the ContentResolver. Here's an example:

```
  //get columns
  int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
  int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
  int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
  //add songs to list
  do {
    long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
    songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
  }
```

Now if I add album, genre, and other information to the Song object as well, you can imagine that this wouldn't look pretty. Here's an option I'm considering but I wanted to know if there's a better way:

Use Uri.parse(..) to turn strings into Uris after keeping String representations of all attributes in an array such as [Title, Artist, Album,..]. Problem: Not all datatypes are Strings so putting the returned values in one Collection is messy. Also, when passing it to Song constructor, I would probably have to pass each element by index(and thus make my code dependent on the indexing of the String array).

I know I'm probably overthinking it, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: so you are using content provider ... then if you wana show Cursor in ListView , do not use Song model at all, but use Loaders API + CursorAdapter ...

Comment: I don't necessarily want to show all columns in the ListView but I will look into what you have said. This is my first serious Android project so I'm still a little green on how the framework works.